# typing a fixed character between each letter of each word in a word document

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word document. what I want to do is I want to insert a fixed character between each letter of each word. for example, if I want to insert i, the word would now look like isiuipieir, formerly which was super. how to do that?

Comment: [Finding and replacing characters using wildcards](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm)

Comment: This is really big. Can you please suggests me which section I should look for to solve the issue

Comment: You'd be better copying the text into Notepad++, and using a macro to insert a letter, then move the cursor right, rinse and repeat.

Comment: Can I directly do that with word?

Comment: Can you specify the requirement in a bit more detail? For instance, what do you expect to happen with punctuation, number, words with numbers in them, words with apostrophes in them, etc?

Comment: Word has a full macro function. It probably wouldn't be difficult to record a macro that inserts a character, moves the cursor one character over, then repeats this.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to do a Find and Replace with Wildcards, as follows.

Find any letter or digit:
`([0-9A-z])`

And replace with `i` and what's was found:
`i\1`

[image]